# Default directives in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm working on a shared sidebar component for my application that will be reused by a few modules.

Using the sidebar in the Users module, for example, might look like the following:

```html
<sidebar>
  <sidebar-item title="Users"
                   icon="people"
                   routerLink="/users"
                   routerLinkActive="active"
                   [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"></sidebar-item>

  <sidebar-item title="Create User"
                   icon="add_circle"
                   routerLink="/users/create"
                   routerLinkActive="active"
                   [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"></sidebar-item>

  <sidebar-item title="Manage Users"
                   icon="edit"
                   routerLink="/users/manage"
                   routerLinkActive="active"
                   [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"></sidebar-item>
</sidebar>
```

This code will look pretty similar in other modules. Internally, the sidebar component is rendering it's children in an `<ng-content>` block gets access to the children using `@ContentChildren`.

What I'm trying to workaround is the need to specify `routerLinkActive` and `routerLinkActiveOptions` on each instance of `sidebar-item`. They're always going to be the same and for the styling to work, `routerLinkActive` needs to always be set to `active`.

Is there any way I can get this to work without needing to repeat those directives (either by setting a default value or by other means)?

Answer (score 1):

You could have the sidebar-item to be data-driven:

```
<sidebar-item *ngFor="let item of items" [title]="item.title"
               [icon]="item.icon"
               [routerLink]="item.link"
               routerLinkActive="active"
               [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"></sidebar-item>
```

Where `items` is:

```
[
   {  title: 'Users', icon: 'people', link:'/users' },
   {  title: 'Create User', icon: 'add_circle', link:'/users/create' },
   {  title: 'Manage Users', icon: 'edit', link:'/users/manage' }
]
```

Comment: Yeah, but the sidebar component will be reused in multiple modules (it's basically a contextual menu that shows links related to the current module). If I have 6 modules using the sidebar component, that code will be copied 6 times.

Comment: Code could be part of the component class that's shared.